# Facebook canvas is blank

Tags: php, facebook

I just wanted to wrap my php form with Facebook canvas, but it shows me blank screen. When I try the form directly, it works great. What should I do? I'm not using any SDK, because I don't need any permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and since I cant leave comment. I will just say this. Check to make sure the exact file is referenced not just the directory its in. i.e Page Tab URL: domain/directory/index.html. and soon you will need a https version also.

Comment: I have a SSL certificate. And everything is correctly filled :/ still nothing, FB is requesting my page and then stops.

Comment: and your using absolute URL paths including the https part ? also you have the Facebook js running on your page ? I had something similar where the server was handling the request weird. But I just changed the server. Sorry that's all I got.

Comment: Yes, absolute URL with https path. Without any FB JS SDK, but when I add fb-js inicialization, it stays the same. That is strange, because my other apps work. Thank you for the hints, anyway